# Why the database is not refreshing after delete?

Tags: python, json, flask, sqlite

in the DB I have two events:

```
{1: {'title': 'APPLE'}, 2: {'title': 'BANANA'}}
```

as you can see bellow, I am calling the deletefromDB function on refresh with the parameter of the second event and I am printing out the data (the json above). My issue is, that the data will change, only after I restart my flask server. Till that point it's the same json output. Can somebody explain what I am doing wrong?

this is my code:

```
import sqlite3
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
app = Flask(__name__)
data = {}

conn = sqlite3.connect('events.db')
cursor = conn.cursor()

# INIT
def initDB():
    with conn:
        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM Events")
        rows = cursor.fetchall()
        for row in rows:
            temp = {}
            temp["title"] = row[1]
            data[row[0]] = temp
        print(data)
initDB()

def deletefromDB(eventID):
    query = 'DELETE FROM Events WHERE EventId = {}'.format(eventID)
    with conn:
       cursor.execute(query)
    print(query)
    initDB()

@app.route('/')
def index():
    deletefromDB(2)
    return 'Index Page'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Comment: Looks like a problem with transactions. Try executing "commit" manually maybe or changing the isolation_level to None.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are caching the tables result into the `data` dict on database initialization. Then you delete a row from the table without committing the changes to the `data` dict. Either you reload the entire `data` dict after deletion or you remove the entry directly from it:

```
def deletefromDB(eventID):
    query = 'DELETE FROM Events WHERE EventId = {}'.format(eventID)
    with conn:
       cursor.execute(query)
    del data[eventID]
    print(query)
    initDB()
```

Be careful, you create a formatted SQL string without escaping the parameter (SQL Injection alert). Use the cursor execute to substitute the variables.

```
query = 'DELETE FROM Events WHERE EventId = %d'
# ...
cursor.execute(query, (eventID,))
```

Do it whenever you substitute something into a SQL query!

Comment: yeah, after I submited the question I found the issue. but thanks

Comment: one more question: how to re init the data dict? as If I do data = {} in  the deletefromDB func, nothing happens